# Reprojecting WGS84 to Winkel-Tripel with new prime meridian breaks polygons

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, proj

I've been trying to re-project a rather large shapefile of the ocean's polygons ([found here](https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/data/water-polygons.html)) to a Winkel-Tripel using a prime meridian of -96 (US) rather than the standard 0. However, I'm noticing that this appears to break some polygons and stretch across the map; my understanding is that this occurs when an object crosses the dateline border.

Is there a solution that could be applied (ideally using Shapely or another Python library on a GeoPandas dataframe, though I'm also open to editing the shapefile itself in QGIS) to automatically fix this based on the assumption that I'll continue using -96 as the meridian?  I can get a workaround by using a PROJ string with "+over", but this also adjusts the shape of the projection and the corresponding "pseudo-coordinates"

Below is the code I'm currently using; rather simple as of now!

```
import geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

zipfile = "zip://data/shapefiles/water-polygons-split-4326.zip"
water = geopandas.read_file(zipfile)

water_tri = water.to_crs("+proj=wintri +pm=-96")
water_tri.plot()
```